# Can i know how many partitions and their names has a drive from C#?

Tags: c#

I need to recognize from an aplication in .NET if a drive has a specific non Windows partition. Can this be acchieved from C#? Logically I just need to know if the partition is present, I don't need to read in it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some prototype C# classes to get you started:

**How To: (Almost) Everything In WMI via C# - Part 3: Hardware**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EverythingInWmi03.aspx?msg=2310667

There is also this:
[**An in-depth look at WMI and Instrumentation: Part II**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/klaus_salchner@hotmail.com/WMIPart211162005021718AM/WMIPart2.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried it myself, but the `System.Management.ManagementObject` class and its associated types give you access to WMI capabilities.  One of these WMI types

```
Win32_DiskDrive
Win32_DiskPartition
Win32_LogicalDisk
```

might do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx), I would assume that you could use System.Management as suggested above. Using the Win32_DiskPartition key you could count the number of partitions returned. Something like

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from " + "Win32_DiskPartition");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();

MessageBox.Show("Number of partitions" + moc.Count);
```